# how to deploy Angular Environment variables in Vercel?

Tags: angular, deployment, environment-variables, vercel, dotenv

How to deploy my angular application in Vercel with my environment variables.

Here's my GitHub repo of this project = https://github.com/TarunUM/clipped

I've tried using 'dotenv' in my environment and the application run perfectly but when I tried to build it from 'ng build' but it threw errors like : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMqCX.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In order to access environment variables, we have to use **process.env.API_KEY**. But we cannot simply just run this snippet on browser side code. So, in order to solve this issue I have created a script which basically writes content to `environment.ts` file.

```
const setEnv = () => {
const fs = require('fs');
const writeFile = fs.writeFile;
const targetPath = './src/environments/environment.ts';
const colors = require('colors');
require('dotenv').config({
  path: 'src/environments/.env'
});
// `environment.ts` file structure
const envConfigFile = `export const environment = {
apiKey: '${**process.env.API_KEY**}',
production: true,
};
`;
writeFile(targetPath, envConfigFile, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
});
setEnv();
```

And then don't forget to add this script to your package.json file. In my case, I am working with Nx workspace so it looks something like this.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nx serve",
"build": "node config.js && nx build",
"test": "nx test",
```

},

Now, you can simply run `npm run build` which will override the content of your environment.ts file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYZZH.png)

Hope this helps!
Good day